# SSRS Single Report prompting for user / pass

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

- SQL Developer 2019
- SSRS 2019

I restored my reporting database, SQL services to a new computer, restored databases, etc. I'm running everything on my localhost.

I have 20 reports I can access from the web SSRS ReportServer URL; only 1 of the 20 is prompting me for a user/pass before running the report.

I created copies of a working report and copies of the broken report with new names to test to see if something was cached. The broken copy is still broken (different name) and the working copy (different name) works.

I managed the reports, compared database sources and credentials between working an broken and they match.

I deleted the broken report, added it net new again, still prompts for the user/pass before opening the report.

Any idea why a single report would be corrupt like this; is there anything I can look at within the RDL?

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but the credentials are required by the datasource. If its the same datasource and it works for other reports, then maybe this particular report is attempting to do something on the SQL Server which the credentials don't allow. For example maybe all other reports are a straight query and this report attempts to run a stored procedure, and the user doesn't have permissions to run a stored procedure. Thats all I can think of - something along those lines anyway, you can also have table/view level permissions etc

Comment: As Dale K suggests, I would go back and check the data source. Make sure it's exactly the same name as your working report. Data sources are not overwritten during deployment by default so it might be you have two data sources both with similar names. You can actually change the data source that a report points to within the web portal via the 'manage' menu as a quick test.

Comment: Thanks guys.  So working report and nonworking report both use the same shared datasource. 
If i go to that datasource via localhosts/Reports datasources I can test connection and the datasource is using integrated security.

Also both reports run store procedures, so don't think it's tied to that level of permission.

Appreciate the help!